# Crystal Reports SubReport parameter has multiple values

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a report where I have created a subreport that uses a parameter from the main report but that value in the main report returns multiple of the parameter. Is there a way to specify in the parameter to only pull a distinct value into the parameter?

Answer (score 0):

You could write a Formula to filter out the parameters you don't want, then pass that entire Formula as a parameter to the subreport.